# Expandable listview data model design

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I have data something of this sought

```
id      time     name
1       42589    lion
2       62589    tiger
2       78976    zebra
3       86478    Monkey
4       95689    sheep
4       96895    deer
```

Now , the grouping should be done in such a way that, the items with id "2" should be grouped and a row with id 2 and time "62589" should be shown. Only on click of this row, a new child with id 2 and time "78976" should be shown. The same rule aplies for rows with id "4"

The above data is contained in an arraylist -ArrayList assetlist;
The POJO Asset has the setter and getter methods for id, time and name.
How should this be implemented in an expandable listview?